Unable to run pipeline using Jenkins Shared Library
I have a particular jenkins instance that is unable to run shared library. Note it is able to pull library but it throws the error below. I have ensure I am using latest groovy pipeline plugin. Not sure what the issue is at this point
> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe ls-remote -h -- git@bitbucket.org:***/jenkinslibrary.git # timeout=10
Found match: refs/heads/main revision f56d212d13db054faf6090ec4b77f31d25366c59
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: X:\workspaces\Bitbucket_Shared_Library2@libs: Unable to determine if root directory exists
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:782)
    at hudson.FilePath.mkdirs(FilePath.java:3756)
    at hudson.FilePath$Write.invoke(FilePath.java:2561)
    at hudson.FilePath$Write.invoke(FilePath.java:2549)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1236)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1219)
    at hudson.FilePath.write(FilePath.java:2546)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.SCMBasedRetriever.doRetrieve(SCMBasedRetriever.java:198)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.SCMSourceRetriever.retrieve(SCMSourceRetriever.java:79)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.LibraryAdder.retrieve(LibraryAdder.java:264)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.LibraryAdder.add(LibraryAdder.java:151)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.LibraryDecorator$1.call(LibraryDecorator.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1087)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:624)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:602)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:579)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:293)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox$Scope.parse(GroovySandbox.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:190)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:175)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:635)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:581)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:335)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:442)
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: Loading libraries failed

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:309)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1107)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:624)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:602)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:579)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:293)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox$Scope.parse(GroovySandbox.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:190)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:175)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:635)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:581)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:335)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:442)
Finished: FAILURE

Updated plugins, restarted jenkins server


Can you run any pipelines that allocate workspace on that instance? Because from the message it sounds like X:\workspaces might be missing.

Allocate Workspace and also Add your Shared Library Folder Structure, it will be more helpful.

Other pipelines that use that same workspace works as expected but as soon as you import the share library it throws the same error. Also this same error is also been thrown for pull request multibranch pipeline. Also added my sharedlibrary config above

@bugsy5923 It seems your library configuration is fine from the Jenkins side. How are you referring to it? Are you importing it properly? Share your Jenkins script as well.

I am referencing it by importing it on the pipeline
@Library("Jenkins-SharedLibrary") _
pipeline {
//pipeline code
}
